# Java / Eclipse (WindowBuilder plugin) - how do I effectively use Swing Actionlisteners?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

My question is specific to Eclipse and the Swing WindowBuilder plugin.

To make simple Swing apps I normally create a class and extend a JFrame.  I make my Swing components private class variables.  This allows me to add an Actionlisteners and access the swing components in actionPerformed(), like this:

```
public class MyClass() extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click me");

    public MyClass() {
        super("title");
        this.setLayout(null);
        btnClickMe.setBounds(1,1,100,100);
        this.add(btnClickMe);
        btnClickMe.addActionListener(this);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if(source == btnClickMe) { // do something }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
    }
}
```

By default the WindowBuilder plugin create Swing component variables I guess in what would be considered the constructor (public MyClass()), rather than private class variables.  As a result due to scope I am not able to use ActionListeners the way I am used to since the Swing variables are not visible to actionPerformed().

Can anyone advise how this can be overcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's stopping you from refactoring those local variables to fields? One of the best things about WindowBuilder is able to parse hand written code to some extent.

Besides, there's a configuration option in Window Builder to create field variables for controls. Look in Eclipse, `Preferences->WindowBuilder->Swing->Code generation` ;)

Comment: Thanks this answered my question.  I am new to Eclipse and have never used the refactoring feature - looks like it will work perfectly!  Additionally, I was not even sure where to find plug in preferences.  I will modify the preferences going forward.  Thanks again.